# 3.6.4 Strogatz dynamical systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

The question says:
What happens if you add a small imperfection to a system that has a saddle node bifurcation?

Not really sure. I want to say that it depends. If you are at the bifurcation point, then a small disturbance will result in a qualitative change i.e equilibria will be added or will disappear. What do you think this question is asking?

Comment: So something of the form $\frac{dx}{dt}=\epsilon+ r+x^2$? But then doesn't really change anything does it

Comment: In that case $x^{*}= +-\sqrt(\frac{r}{1+\epsilon})$. We still get similarly shaped curves

Comment: ok that's what I thought but... if it were possible for it to be perturbed away what would that look like?